# MariaDB slow log is not written after logrotate

Tags: mysql, logrotate

I got a problem with the logrotate of one of our MariaDB servers. Logrotate is running without (apperently) throwing any errors. After rotating the mariadb-slow.log file MariaDB is not writing any messages into the new log file.
The problem affects only the mariadb-slow.log.

When I run the mysqladmin command from the postrotate section of the logrotate configuration file, the maraidb-slow.log is getting written again.

```
mysqladmin --defaults-file="/etc/mysql/debian.cnf" --local flush-error-log flush-engine-log flush-general-log flush-slow-log
```

Running logrotate manually is also leading to the issue.

```
logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server
```

Adding the -v parameter shows nothing noticable

```
logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server
Reading state from file: /var/lib/logrotate/status
Allocating hash table for state file, size 64 entries
Creating new state
...
Creating new state

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/mysql/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log /var/log/mysql/error.log  1024 bytes (7 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
  log /var/log/mysql/mysql.log does not exist -- skipping
considering log /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
  log /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log does not exist -- skipping
considering log /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
  Now: 2017-11-15 15:02
  Last rotated at 2017-11-15 13:54
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/mysql/error.log
  Now: 2017-11-15 15:02
  Last rotated at 2017-11-15 13:54
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log, log->rotateCount is 7
dateext suffix '-20171115'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log.7.gz to /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log.8.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 7),
renaming /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log.6.gz to /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log.7.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 6),
old log /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log.6.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log.5.gz to /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log.6.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 5),
renaming /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log.4.gz to /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log.5.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 4),
renaming /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log.3.gz to /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log.4.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 3),
renaming /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log.2.gz to /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log.3.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 2),
renaming /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log.1.gz to /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log.2.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 1),
renaming /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log.0.gz to /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log.1.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 0),
old log /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log.0.gz does not exist
rotating log /var/log/mysql/error.log, log->rotateCount is 7
dateext suffix '-20171115'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/log/mysql/error.log.7.gz to /var/log/mysql/error.log.8.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 7),
renaming /var/log/mysql/error.log.6.gz to /var/log/mysql/error.log.7.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 6),
renaming /var/log/mysql/error.log.5.gz to /var/log/mysql/error.log.6.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 5),
renaming /var/log/mysql/error.log.4.gz to /var/log/mysql/error.log.5.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 4),
renaming /var/log/mysql/error.log.3.gz to /var/log/mysql/error.log.4.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 3),
renaming /var/log/mysql/error.log.2.gz to /var/log/mysql/error.log.3.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 2),
renaming /var/log/mysql/error.log.1.gz to /var/log/mysql/error.log.2.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 1),
renaming /var/log/mysql/error.log.0.gz to /var/log/mysql/error.log.1.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 0),
old log /var/log/mysql/error.log.0.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log to /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log.1
creating new /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log mode = 0640 uid = 110 gid = 4
renaming /var/log/mysql/error.log to /var/log/mysql/error.log.1
creating new /var/log/mysql/error.log mode = 0640 uid = 110 gid = 4
running postrotate script
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
removing old log /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log.8.gz
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
removing old log /var/log/mysql/error.log.8.gz
```

The logrotate configuration file is the one from the package maintainer. I didn't do any modifications. I also tried some other things.

```
/var/log/mysql/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log /var/log/mysql/error.log {
        # daily
        size 1k
        rotate 7
        missingok
        create 640 mysql adm
        compress
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
          test -x /usr/bin/mysqladmin || exit 0
          if [ -f `my_print_defaults --mysqld | grep -m 1 -oP "pid-file=\K.+$"` ]; then
            # If this fails, check debian.conf!
            mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf -v --local flush-error-log \
              flush-engine-log flush-general-log flush-slow-log >> /var/log/mysql-logrotate.log 2>&1
          fi
        endscript
}
```

After the learning about the issue I just added the

```
>> /var/log/mysql-logrotate.log 2>&1
```

But the mysql-logrotate.log stays empty.

Software used:
OS: Debian 9.1
DB: MariaDB 10.1
Logrotate: 3.11.0

Answer (score 1):

Ok, when I put the following into the postrotate BEFORE the mysqladmin command

```
test -x /usr/bin/mysql || exit 0
          mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf -e "FLUSH SLOW LOGS;"
```

the mariadb-slow.log is rotated AND can be written after the rotation.